# how can i add user inputs into csv file with dictwriter

Tags: python, string, user-interface, variables, format

below is the part of my code that I can write header. 
But now, I want to save the user inputs to the CSV file.

```
def action2():
with open(r'C:\Users\admin\new python course\PYPROG\bday.csv','a',newline='') as f:
    # data=writer(f)
    # data.writerow(['name','birthdate'])
    win2=tk.Tk()
    win2.title('enter names and birthdate')
    name_lable=ttk.Label(win2,text='enter your name-->')  #display it on window
    name_lable.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=tk.W)
    date_lable=ttk.Label(win2,text='enter your birthdate-->')  #display it on window
    date_lable.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=tk.W)
    name_var=tk.StringVar()
    name_entry_box=ttk.Entry(win2,width=19,textvariable=name_var)
    name_entry_box.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=tk.W)
    name_entry_box.focus()
    date_var=tk.StringVar()
    date_entry_box=ttk.Entry(win2,width=19,textvariable=date_var)
    date_entry_box.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=tk.W)
    dict_writer=DictWriter(f,fieldnames=['names','birthdate']) 
    if os.stat('bday.csv').st_size==0:
        dict_writer.writeheader()
    def submitnameanddate():
        pass
    submit_button=ttk.Button(win2,text='submit',command=submitna
```

how can I add user inputs into CSV file with `dictwriter`

Comment: Please check your code in the question. It looks like it's not complete.

Comment: Edit your question: there is one part which should be a block of code which isn't. It's difficult to help you out when we have to guess what you did.